# Rasterize sf object in R (desired cell values 1 and 0)

Tags: raster, r, vector, rasterization

I have a vector file (multipolygon) in class sf, which I want to turn into a raster of a certain extent. I need all the areas where polygons are located to be value 1 and all areas where no polygons occure to be 0. I will multiply this raster afterwards with a classified one in order to mask out areas.
The function rasterize_vector_layer from the EnMApToolBox in QGIS is doing this when setting the parameters 'init'=0 and 'burn_value' = 1.

[image]

How can this be done with the sf_rasterize function in R? The function always takes the variables of the vector into account, which isn't really neccessary.

```
> st_rasterize(st_read(connex,query="SELECT * FROM schlaege;"))
stars object with 2 dimensions and 9 attributes
attribute(s):
                              Min.      1st Qu.       Median         Mean      3rd Qu.         Max.  NA's
id                    4.977000e+03 5.538890e+05 1.233345e+06 1.202341e+06 1.856582e+06 2.528323e+06 30017
fid                   0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 30017
FS_KENNUNG            7.385270e+07 7.387385e+07 7.396696e+07 7.498410e+07 7.522718e+07 7.972772e+07 30017
SL_FLAECHE_BRUTTO_HA  5.000771e-01 3.114862e+00 5.082015e+00 6.732785e+00 7.922672e+00 5.825722e+01 30017
GEO_ID                4.336396e+06 4.405085e+06 4.456749e+06 3.055837e+07 1.011450e+08 1.026277e+08 30017
GEO_PART_KEY          2.200000e+01 2.200000e+01 2.200000e+01 2.200000e+01 2.200000e+01 2.200000e+01 30017
LOG_PKEY              2.000000e+00 2.000000e+00 2.000000e+00 2.000000e+00 2.000000e+00 2.000000e+00 30017
FART_ID               1.612000e+03 1.612000e+03 1.612000e+03 1.612000e+03 1.612000e+03 1.612000e+03 30017
GML_LENGTH            3.400000e+02 4.460000e+02 5.180000e+02 6.886557e+02 7.210000e+02 3.052700e+04 30017
dimension(s):
  from  to  offset    delta                refsys point x/y
x    1 373  614218  87.5717 WGS 84 / UTM zone 33N FALSE [x]
y    1 175 5346467 -87.5717 WGS 84 / UTM zone 33N FALSE [y]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `st_rasterize` on any attribute, and filter through `!is.na`. For example, use the first attribute:

```
nc = st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
x = !is.na(st_rasterize(nc[,1]))
plot(x)
```

[image]

I'm not certain what will happen if any of the attribute are NA, so for absolute safety you could:

```
rasterize_shape <- function(shape){
 shape$X = 1
 st_rasterize(shape["X"])
}
```

which returns a raster of 1 inside and NA outside, or:

```
rasterize_shape <- function(shape){
 shape$X = 1
 !is.na(st_rasterize(shape["X"]))
}
```

which returns 1 inside, 0 outside.